# Controlling for-loop output

Tags: php, for-loop

Is it possible to control a for-loop when it reaches a certain condition?

Explanation:

I'm retrieving the folder path to a collection of images from a database: these images are then printed out via a for-loop. What I would need to do is control how these images are displayed on the page (say, 5 images per row).
As of now, the for-loop prints out 40 images in a single row, which makes you scroll to the furthest right of the page.

Is there a solution for controlling the for-loop, as in for instance, after 5 successful loops, echo out a < br >? Here's a vulgar thought:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $rows; $i++) {
$path = $image[$i];
$folder_path = $path['folder_path']; //since it's an array
echo '<img src="' . $folder_path . '">';

//pseudocode
if ($i == 5) {
echo '<br>';
...continue with the loop
}
}
```

I know the pseudocode looks crazy, but that's pretty much what I need to do: loop for x amount of instances, add something, then continue.

Comment: Use the modulo operator, as in `$i % 5 == 0` to do something every fifth iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The same loop. The condition for inserting the 
 is ($i % 5 == 0), which means (if this element is the fifth one of his series) will be useful for you.

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i < $rows; $i++) {
  $path = $image[$i];
  $folder_path = $path['folder_path']; 
  echo '<img src="' . $folder_path . '">';

  if ($i % 5 == 0) {
    echo '<br>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain a litle bit what you do in your code.

Answer (score 1):

As per @m69's comment, the best option would be to use the `%` (modulus) comparison operator. As explained by the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

> $a % $b returns the remainder of $a divided by $b.

So, in your case:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {

    $path = $image[$i];
    $folder_path = $path['folder_path']; //since it's an array
    echo '<img src="' . $folder_path . '">';

    if ($i % 5 == 0) { //do this if $i divided by 5 has a remainder of 0
        echo '<br>';
    }

}
```

As a side note, you should set `$i` to 0 at the beginning of your for loop, assuming `$rows` is set to the number of rows returned from your query. Setting it to 1 will keep it from iterating through the last row, because `$i` will `== 40` (assuming 40 rows), and so will NOT be `< 40`.

Comment: What the modulus is doing here is that it adds the < br > prior to echoing out the images and the result remains the same: the images are printed in a single row, but they are pushed down, due to the use of modulus. It seems that in echoing out the array, the images are being treated as one element. I tried with foreach, but got the same result. The folder path is being retrieved with fetchAll(), then the relevant array position is stored in a var. I solved the issue though, with css (added a class and float: left). I also removed the < td > that wrapped the img and now it works.

Comment: If you have solved the problem and none of these answers fully answer your question, please either: 1) post your own answer and accept it as the best answer, or 2) consider deleting your question from SO.

Comment: I can't delete it because the thread has answers. I tagged the question for deletion. Even though I solved my issue, my solution doesn't answer the question: namely, to separate the images between (as with < br > with the for-loop. I tested doing this for string and it worked just like you guys said it would. It just seems not to be working for the images it echoes out from folder.